# CML Latch simulation in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, analog, integrated-circuit, ltspice, latch

I am trying to simulate a CML Latch in LTSpice (schematic below), but the simulation results do not seem right. I am using N_50n transistors from BSIM4 model. L = 60n for all transistors, W = 10u for M1-4 and W = 5u for M5-6. The output makes sense in terms of binary, but the voltage level is low and unstable. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Is it about the parameters or a mistake in the circuit itself?

[image: Schematic]

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this type of structure, but my guess is that latches require realistic propagation delays to function properly.  You haven't posted a source for your MOSFET models, so it's impossible for someone to test out your circuit and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I downloaded the model txt from cmosedu.org. I used N_50n transistors from the text file below:

https://cmosedu.com/cmos1/cmosedu_models.txt

Comment: This is what I get when I duplicate your circuit, but don't ground `DIN-` and add capacitance to the outputs to stabilize the feedback.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT8nD.png